# Rails 7 flash errors not displaying in application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, alert, message

Having an issue in my Rails 7 app of alerts not showing up.

`notices`, however, are.

I am displaying alerts in `application.html.erb` using `<%= alert %>`

```
<%= render partial: "shared/navbar" %>
<div class="px-6">
  <div class="mt-6"></div>
  <div>

    <% if notice %>
      <div class="notification is-success is-light text-center">
        <%= notice %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <% if alert %>
      <% debugger %>
      <div class="notification is-danger is-light text-center">
        <%= alert %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have added a "FAILED" logger to my controller action, which I am seeing in the Rails logs.  This proves to me that we are indeed falling into the "else" condition, and the `new` page is being rendered upon failure to create a new object.  However, I do not see the alert message.

```
def create
@rescue = AnimalRescue.new(rescue_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @rescue.save
    format.html { redirect_to animal_rescue_url(@rescue), notice: "Rescue was successfully created." }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @rescue }
  else
    Rails.logger.info "FAILED"
    format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity, alert: "Unable to create rescue." }
    format.json { render json: @rescue.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rb
format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity, alert: "Unable to create rescue." }
# NOTE:                              not a render option  ^^^^^^
```

`:alert` and `:notice` are options for `redirect_to` method, which set the corresponding `flash` message:

```rb
flash[:alert] = "Unable to create rescue."
```

Also, `flash` will only display on the next request after the redirect. To display a flash message in the current request you have to use `flash.now`:

```rb
format.html do
  flash.now.alert = "Unable to create rescue."
  render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

In case your form is inside of the turbo frame, you'll need to display an alert from within the frame.

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating it. It will be waaay easier and more flexible to just use the same logic to display all kinds of flash messages as the only thing that needs to change is a single CSS class :

```
<% flash.each do |type, msg| %>
  <%= tag.div msg, 
              class: [
                {
                   notice: 'is-success',
                   alert: 'is-danger'
                   # etc
                }.fetch(type.to_sym, type.to_s), 
                "notification", 
                "is-light", 
                "text-center"
              ]
  %>
<% end %>
```

The flash is after all just a simple hash like object that contains strings. KISS.

Comment: This can of course be refactored into a helper method.